# Using varables in sql spatial data

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial-query, sqlgeography

I am attempting to write an sql stored procedure that will determine if a point is within a buffer. So far I have been able to hard code the values in the query and they work as expected but when I attempt to replace the hard coded values with variables then I get problems.

This works:

```
DECLARE @g geography;   
Declare @Latitude float; 
declare @Longitude float;

Set @g = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(@longitude as VARCHAR(16)) + ' ' + CAST(@latitude as VARCHAR(16)) + ')', 4326)

declare @bufloc geography = geography::Point(52.677777, -1.280786,
 4326).STBuffer(1000)

SELECT CASE @g.STIntersects(@bufloc)  WHEN 1 THEN '@g intersects @h'  
 ELSE '@g does not intersect @h'   
END;
```

But if I declare a second set of coordinates and the try to pass variables into the @bufloc I break the query.

```
Declare @BufLongitude float; Declare @DistanceInMeteres int;

declare @bufloc geography = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' +
CAST(@BufLatitude as VARCHAR(16)) + ' ' + CAST(@BufLongitude as
VARCHAR(16)) + ')', 4326).STBuffer(1000)
```

How would I write this to get things working? Ultimatly I would like to pass two coordinates into a stored procedure along with a distance parameter to use in the construction of the buffer and return true or false if the point can be located in the resulting buffer.

The query returns a false value it returns '@g does not intersect @h'  when the hard coded query returns '@g intersects @h'  for the same value.

Comment: What do you mean by "break the query"? Is there an error you're getting, or are the results wrong? [Seems to work fine on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=57a0d0c9d0d0bc67a44f76b7f2577695) and my server.

Comment: The query doesn't  cause an error it gives a false result I know that the point is approx 940 metres from the buffer centre but when I push values through that are greater than 940 it still gives a 'does not intersect' result!

Comment: Could it be because you pass lon as first param when creating `@g` and as second for `@bufloc`? You have lon/lat switched between them. At least that's how it is in the question.

Comment: Doh...  well spotted I was looking at that for ages and didn't see the error. Thank you.